# java grouping issue

Tags: java, grouping

I have an arralist of type asset, where asset is a POJO and has its set and get methods.

```
ArrayList<Asset> assetItems;
```

each asset has a ratingValue and 
it can be fetched by

```
assetItems.get(i).getratingValue();
```

Now the task is the assetItems should be grouped based on their rating value . Could some one help me on this

For Example
Initially if the ratingvalue of the items in the arraylist are
a
c
g
a
j
c

then the output should be
a
a
c
c
g
j

Comment: What do u mean by grouping? Like organize all objects below some threashold etc?

Comment: or something like this? http://www.anzaan.com/2010/06/grouping-objects-using-objects-property/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean grouping, then have a look at Jon Skeet solution.
If you mean sorting, then you can use this code:

```
Collections.sort(assetItems, new Comparator<Asset>() {
    public int compare(Asset a1, Asset a2) {
        return a1.getratingValue().compareTo(a2.getratingValue());
    }
};
```

Comment: the ratingvalue is a string. Could thsi logic be used

Comment: @sonysamsung Yes, without problems, just use compareTo() instead. I edited my post to illustrate that

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a [`Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) from [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) is what you want:

```
Multimap<String, Asset> map = Multimaps.newListMultimap();
for (Asset asset : assetItems) {
    map.put(asset.getRatingValue(), asset);
}
```

Then you can get all the assets with a particular rating:

```
for (Asset asset : map.get(someRating)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Im not supposed to use external jars:(

Comment: @sonysamsung: Any other requirements you didn't think to mention in the question? (Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) You could always build your own `Multimap` implementation, of course - just backed by a `Map<K, List<V>>`.

Comment: these are the only requirements. I shouldnt use external jars

Comment: @sonysamsung: So as I say, implement `Multimap` yourself. Vakimshaar has given an initial bit of implementation, which you can adapt appropriately. (If you'd given more information in your question, you wouldn't have had to adapt it as much.) Giving you the full code for what is presumably homework wouldn't be a good idea, as you wouldn't really learn much.

Comment: :) Im new to java..In VakimSHaar's reply, how could I access the List from the map?

Comment: @sonysamsung: If you're new to Java, I suggest you start by reading the Java Collections tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like:

```
Map<Integer, List<Asset>> groupedAssets = new HashMap<Integer,  List<Asset>>()
for(Asset asset : assetItems) {
    int ratingValue = asset.getratingValue();
    List<Asset> assets = groupedAssets.get(ratingValue);
    if(assets == null) { // this rating value has never been retrieved before
        assets = new ArrayList<Asset>();
        groupedAssets.put(ratingValue, assets);
    }
    assets.add(asset);
}
```

The resulting `Map` contains the list of `Asset` grouped by `ratingValue`

Comment: I am not answering as you have added an example. But I keep my answer in case it may help anybody!

Answer (score 0):

you can group Assets based on threshold value like this.

```
    Class AssetGroup
    {
    int thresholdrating;
    ArrayList<Asset> listAssets;

   // add Asset to group list

   public void add(Asset a)
   {
    this.listAssets = a;
   }

    }
```